# Both Domain Controllers believe that they are the PDC and FSMO owners

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain, domain-controller, fsmo

We have 2 DC's in the environment, 1 VM in Hyper-V and 1 Physical Server for redundancy and backup fail over.
Last week the (C:) OS HDD in the Physical Server just died and the Server crashed. The Disk is dead, it just clicks, and the no longer Boots.
That Physical Server was the PDC and FSMO role holder, DNS and Print Server.
As a result of it crashing, DNS and Printing failed as well as some other services.

the Question her is this:
If both DC's think that they are the PDC, and FSMO role holder, how do you fix this and get the PDC back to normal?

Comment: Both DC used to get the global catalog ? If yes, just dcpromo a new server and force a removal of the old DC.

Comment: `If both DC's think that they are the PDC, and FSMO role holder, how do you fix this and get the PDC back to normal?` - What do you mean by that? Why would they both see themselves as the FSMO role holder? Do you mean that you seized the FSMO roles to the virtual DC and now you want to bring the physical DC back online? If so, don't. Just build it fresh and DCPROMO it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked so now the 2 Server are showing that only the 1 Server is the main PDC from: netdom query fsmo and from ADDS - Computers and Users when you right click on the Domain root and select Operation master it shows the 1 DC is the Main and it is back to normal.